# qDebug() not showing const std::string&

Tags: c++, string, qt, qdebug

I am trying to use some vector data's name with `struct`. I am trying to get see which name in `qDebug()`

To be more clear:

```
const std::string& testName = "asdfqwer";
qDebug() << testName;
```

It gives en error message in build:

```
Error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'qDebug()() << testName'
```

I don't have options to change `const std::string&` type. Could you please help me to solve this issue without changing type?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`qDebug()` does not know anything about `std::string` but it works with `const char*`. Appropriate operator you can find [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdebug.html#operator-lt-lt-14). You can achieve this with `data()` or with `c_str()` which is better as `Jiří Pospíšil` said.

For example:

```
const std::string& testName = "asdfqwer";
qDebug() << testName.data() << testName.c_str();
```

Aslo you can convert `std::string` to `QString` with [QString::fromStdString](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html#fromStdString).

Comment: same you can use convertion to the QString with the QString::fromStdString

Comment: Amazing.. I didn't know that behaviours of qDebug()

Comment: It'd be better to use `c_str()` instead of `data()` as the latter is not required to be null-terminated (until C++11).

Comment: @johngull Yes, you are right, but I thought that OP use here C++ only types, but I added this to answer, it correct and OP can choose what he wants.

Comment: @JiříPospíšil I added c_str() to my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Chernobyl I think it is natural to use Qt types if you use qDebug. Impossible to use qDebug without using QtCore, so QString is available for him. Anyway, the main point here that convertion needed.

Answer (score 9):

If you need writing std::string to qDebug() often in your code, you can implement this function globally (for example in you `main.cpp`):

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <string>

QDebug& operator<<(QDebug& out, const std::string& str)
{
    out << QString::fromStdString(str);
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    std::string jau = "jau";
    qDebug() << jau;
    return 0;
}
```